# Help in "An error occurred while uploading the sketch"

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu

Trying to test [THIS](https://github.com/r-downing/PersWiFiManager/tree/master/examples/spiffs_rest_api_nonblocking). Got following error:

```
esptool v0.4.13 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
    setting board to nodemcu
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 9600
    setting port from COM1 to COM3
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    espcomm_upload_file
    espcomm_upload_mem
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
Uploading 356000 bytes from C:\Users\PRAMIT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_521093/testPersWiFiManager.ino.bin to flash at 0x00000000
    erasing flash
    size: 056ea0 address: 000000
    first_sector_index: 0
    total_sector_count: 87
    head_sector_count: 16
    adjusted_sector_count: 71
    erase_size: 047000
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    setting serial port timeouts to 15000 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
    writing flash
................................................................................ [ 22% ]
................................................................................ [ 45% ]
................................................................................ [ 68% ]
.......................An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

All libraries are included, no compile error.
Steps followed:
1st uploaded the data using `Tools>ESP8266 Sketch data upload`.
Then `Sketch>upload`

After failing this, I tried a basic example similar to [THIS](https://github.com/squix78/esp8266-getting-started/blob/master/Exercise_04_04_Solution/Exercise_04_04_Solution.ino). This uploaded successfully. The same configuration is used for both scenarios.

What am I missing? I am getting no clue.

Settings:

[image: Settings]

Comment: Any change in `Erase Flash` settings?

Comment: the data upload was successful? try 115200 baud or more for upload

Comment: @Juraj, you are right, I updated the baud rate to 115200 and it worked. However, I first tried to change it in the code, but not helped.

Comment: upload speed for flashing has nothing to do with the value in sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upload to esp8266 with esptool used in IDE doesn't work good on slow baudrate. It fails for larger sketches. You can upload to NodeMcu at 921600 baud.